# Taking an Arbitrary Power for a Keras Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a custom loss function on Keras where I can choose the power for the subtraction between y_true and y_pred, where y_true and y_pred are their standard definitions with respect to keras loss functions. In other words, I want a loss function that looks like

|y_{true} - y_{pred})^n|

where n is a number that I can choose. I can do this using if n is an integer using `tf.keras.backend.pow` making my loss function:

```
def power_loss(power):
    
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.abs(K.pow(y_true - y_pred, power))
    
    return loss
```

But how can you do this if n is not an integer (for example n=1.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.keras.backend.pow` computes arbitrary powers. You need to cast both arguments to a floating point datatype.

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
K.pow(2.0, 2.5)
```

gives

```
5.656854
```